# ifconfig shows the interface but no IP

Tags: centos, network-interface, ifconfig

I'm troubleshooting some networking issues on our 2-interface centos machine. The machine has two interfaces, for 162.* and 172.* subnetworks. The machine used to work properly but as of today I can only access the machines within the 162.* subnetwork, none of 172.*
I noticed that ipconfig displays the 172.* interface with "scopeid 0x20" instead of the ip address.

ifconfig -a

```
eno16777984: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 162.70.42.93  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 162.70.42.255
        ether 00:50:56:ba:b0:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1935793  bytes 195710508 (186.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 16501  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 638906  bytes 47382225 (45.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno33557248: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feba:6875  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:ba:68:75  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 147161  bytes 8837081 (8.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 639  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8098  bytes 1436275 (1.3 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 318746  bytes 17084987 (16.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 318746  bytes 17084987 (16.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The second interface, eno33557248, instead of the IP shows "scopeid 0x20".

This interface exists under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno33557248. The file reads:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME=eno33557248
UUID="e157d343-3acb-4498-8ab2-83251bf5e098"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR=00:50:56:BA:68:75
IPADDR=172.16.3.2
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=172.16.3.1
```

This file has not changed for years and the machine used to work properly. I don't know why the 172.* interface displays "scopeid 0x20" instead of the IP or what it means but problems with the 172.* subnetwork make me believe there is something wrong about it. If so, how do I fix this interface?

Update1: Output of ip link:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno16777984: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:ba:b0:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno33557248: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:ba:68:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Update2: Content of the other interface file ifcfg-eno16777984

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="no"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eno16777984"
UUID="e157d343-3acb-4498-8ab2-83251bf5e098"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR="00:50:56:BA:B0:83"
DNS1="162.70.113.10"
DNS2="162.70.113.11"
IPADDR=162.70.42.93
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=162.70.42.1
ZONE=public
```

Update3: output of ip route. Note 172.* is not in the list.

```
default via 162.70.42.1 dev eno16777984  proto static  metric 100 
162.70.42.0/24 dev eno16777984  proto kernel  scope link  src 162.70.42.93  metric 100
```

Comment: You do seem to have IPv6 connectivity (and a few MB transferred), right? Please (post or) compare the other file where IPv4 works.

Comment: Please post the output of `ip link` for both i/fs.

Comment: ADded output of ip link

Comment: Added the 162. interface file

Comment: One difference in the config files  is `IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"` vs `IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes`. Do you want to try changing it and rebooting?